# Java Mouse Input Per Second

Tags: java, button, mouseevent

I am coding a Java game that uses mouse actions.  I have a point `msc` in my main class - it gets changed whenever I press the mouse and gets set to `(0, 0)` whenever I release the mouse. For the buttons, they check if `msc` is inside their rectangle, and if so, call `click`.

One of the buttons is supposed to toggle a boolean; when I click on it though, it switches true and false very fast because `msc` gets updated every time `paintComponent` is called.

Here is the code for the button click method:

```
if (button.contains(Screen.msc)) {
    beenClicked = true;
    this.width = this.width - 2;
    this.height = this.height - 2;
    this.x = this.x + 1;
    this.y = this.y + 1;
    g.setColor(currColor);
    textColor = Color.YELLOW;
}
```

but that is not where the problem is I think. Here is the code that changes `msc`:

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    Screen.msc = new Point(0, 0);
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    Screen.msc = new Point((e.getX()) - ((Frame.size.width - Screen.myWidth) / 2), e.getY() - ((Frame.size.height - (Screen.myHeight)) - (Frame.size.width - Screen.myWidth) / 2));
}
```

and the code for what happens when the specific toggle button is clicked:

```
if (toggleToolTips.clicked()) {
    if (Screen.canDrawTooltip) {
        Screen.canDrawTooltip = false;
    } else if(!Screen.canDrawTooltip){
        Screen.canDrawTooltip = true;
    }
}
```

The problem is every time I go and click the button, the boolean switches back and forth real fast.  When I hold it, it just rapidly and continually switches. I would like to make it so that I click once and it switches once.

Comment: ok honestly just please give me some direction instead of just downvoting me.It helps nobody.

Comment: It looks like you need timer. Show us some code and tell us where you are getting exact problems.

Comment: k i added code and stuff. any suggestions?

Comment: I really dont understand your question. Be specific to get better idea.

Comment: ok I have added another thing at the bottom.

Comment: take the time to write a good question and you will get good answers

Comment: I don't really get your question, but have you considered using Thread.sleep(miliseconds) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setting the boolean `beenClicked` but are not checking it anywhere. I would suggest trying

```
if (!beenClicked && toggleToolTips.clicked()) 
{   
    Screen.canDrawTooltip = !Screen.canDrawTooltip);
}
```

And setting `beenClicked` back to false somewhere such as mouseReleased.

Comment: yeah there is a lot more code in other places that do those two things, but the fact remains that every time the screen repaints itself the mouses actions are sent to Screen.mse, setting the x and y for that Point. therefore the button is getting multiple inputs per second which are turning the boolean on and off. that is the problem. I think I may be on the trach to having it worked out now, but further help is much appreciated.

Comment: It worked. I wasnt looking at this very hard and then I read it and think to myself: You are an idiot dude... I cannot believe I didnt think of that! Thanks!